# Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior. In my SwiftUI app

Tags: swiftui

I have this warning and I have no idea where exactly I have to fix. Can somebody know how to fix? UI is working correct but I think it will crush.

Error is typically associated with modifying SwiftUI's state from within a body view update, an onAppear, or similar lifecycle methods. This can lead to unpredictable behavior because SwiftUI's view updates are expected to be idempotent and should not have side effects that modify the state.

ChatsViewModel.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Firebase
import Combine

class ChatsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var chatContacts: [ChatEntity] = []
    private var ref = Database.database().reference()
    private var context: NSManagedObjectContext
    @Published var showOfflineAlert = false
    
    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.context = context
    }
    
    func fetchChatContacts() {
        if NetworkChecker.shared.isConnected {
            fetchFromFirebase()
        } else {
            showOfflineAlert = true
            fetchFromCoreData()
        }
    }

    private func fetchFromFirebase() {
        guard let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let chatsRef = ref.child("Users/\(currentUserId)/Chats")
        chatsRef.observe(.value) { [weak self] snapshot in
            let contactIds = snapshot.children.compactMap { ($0 as? DataSnapshot)?.key }
            self?.matchContactsWithCoreData(contactIds: contactIds)
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchFromCoreData() {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ChatEntity> = ChatEntity.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "hasMessages == %@", NSNumber(value: true))
        do {
            let contacts = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.chatContacts = contacts
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching chat contacts from Core Data: \(error)")
        }
    }

    private func matchContactsWithCoreData(contactIds: [String]) {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ContactEntity> = ContactEntity.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "contactId IN %@", contactIds)
        do {
            let matchedContacts = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            createOrUpdateChatEntities(from: matchedContacts)
        } catch {
            print("Error matching contacts in Core Data: \(error)")
        }
    }

    private func createOrUpdateChatEntities(from contacts: [ContactEntity]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            for contact in contacts {
                let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ChatEntity> = ChatEntity.fetchRequest()
                fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "contactId == %@", contact.contactId ?? "")
                do {
                    let existingChatEntities = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    let chatEntity: ChatEntity = existingChatEntities.first ?? ChatEntity(context: context)
                    chatEntity.contactId = contact.contactId
                    chatEntity.hasMessages = true
                    chatEntity.givenName = contact.givenName
                    chatEntity.familyName = contact.familyName
                    chatEntity.avatarData = contact.avatarData
                } catch {
                    print("Error fetching/updating chat entity: \(error)")
                }
            }
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print("Error saving updated chat entities: \(error)")
            }
        }
            retrieveChatContacts()
        
    }

    private func retrieveChatContacts() {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ChatEntity> = ChatEntity.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "hasMessages == %@", NSNumber(value: true))
        do {
            let contacts = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.chatContacts = contacts
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error retrieving chat contacts from Core Data: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

ChatsView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct ChatsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var chatsViewModel: ChatsViewModel
    @ObservedObject var contactViewModel: ContactViewModel
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State private var isEditing = false
    @State private var showContactsView = false
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(chatsViewModel.chatContacts, id: \.self) { contact in
                    if let contactId = contact.contactId {
                        NavigationLink(destination: MessagesView(context: context, contactId: contactId, contactName: "\(contact.givenName ?? "") \(contact.familyName ?? "")")) {
                            ChatRowView(contact: contact)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            }
            .onAppear {
                chatsViewModel.fetchChatContacts()
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationBarTitle("Chats", displayMode: .inline)
            .sheet(isPresented: $showContactsView) {
                ContactsView(contactViewModel: contactViewModel)
            }
            .refreshable {
                chatsViewModel.fetchChatContacts()
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    if isEditing {
                        Button("Done") {
                            isEditing = false
                        }
                    } else {
                        Button("Edit") {
                            isEditing = true
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    if isEditing {
                        Button("Delete All") {
                            showAlert = true
                        }
                        
                    } else {
                        Button(action: {
                            showContactsView.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(colorScheme == .dark ? AnyView(FlowBackgroundDark()) : AnyView(FlowBackground()))
            .environment(\.editMode, .constant(isEditing ? EditMode.active : EditMode.inactive))
        }
        .alert("You are currently offline or Airplane mode is on. Some features may not be available.", isPresented: $chatsViewModel.showOfflineAlert) {
            Button("OK", role: .cancel) {}
            Button("Settings") {
                if let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString),
                   UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
    }
}

struct ChatRowView: View {
    var contact: ChatEntity
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if let imageData = contact.avatarData, let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
            Text("\(contact.givenName ?? "") \(contact.familyName ?? "")")
        }
    }
}
```

I wrapped core data logic in DispatchQueue but I get the same warning.

Comment: What line does the warning/error point to?

Comment: Here: @Published var chatContacts: [ChatEntity] = []

Comment: If you step back in the debugger, where is it being accessed from? In other words, which line that _sets_ a value is causing a problem?